# I bent CPU socket pins! How to unbent them?

Tags: cpu, motherboard, processor-socket

I have a Intel DG33FB motherboard with a LGA755 (Socket T) CPU socket and a 2.6 GHz LGA755 processor.

I want to upgrade the processor but while doing so I accidentaly bent some pins on the CPU socket. Since the pins are in the socket and not in the CPU I can not just solve this by returning to my old CPU.

Now, with the pins bent, when I try to power up the PC is does not POST.

How I can unbent CPU socket pins safely?

Comment: I have a LGA775 socket, that means that pins are on the motherboard, and there are none on the CPU itself.

Comment: Pins on the MB?  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LGA_775  - those pins bent? whooa. NOT looking good in my eyes.

Comment: I use a pin, sowing needle small enough to fit between the rows.  Any attempt to bend pins could cause them to break, but I have done it this way.  I proceed I row at a time till I find the bent pins.  I slide the needle underneath and very very slowly lift up until it is very close to straight.

Answer (score 0):

> Is the problem in the bent pins? If it is, what is the best way to unbent them?

Maybe, or maybe not...

If you're lucky, and **very careful** (slow!) you might succeed bending them back.
And if you're even more lucky, you didn't cause any more damage to it...  (e.g. [ESD](https://www.google.se/search?&q=ESD)! and breaking the on chip circuitry)

Comment: It can't be ESD, because i had that anti-static bracelet thing on my hands. But how i can bend the pins safely? I am afraid that i will bend them more...

Comment: @jakeGould Agree to that.

Comment: As I **indicated** above, there is no "right way", even if you're VERY careful a pin might have been bent (in the first case) in such way that even attempting to bend it back makes it snap off.

Comment: The pins in the LGA socket... The above might not be as suiting as answer as it seemed at first.